# SQL how to handle multiple value join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I need to join `assignments` and `expatriates` tables by a combination of `ID`, `effective_start_date` and `effective_end_date`.

I need to get data about employees who have gone to another country during their assignment `effective_start_date` and `effective_end_date`. But there is a need to handle cases when during one assignment there have been entered data about employees going to two or more countries - I need to show only one - the last one or the active one (if there is).

In the results I'm getting multiple values for 123 person `ID` and it's because there are incorrect values entered in assignments table - I need to only show only one of this person 123 date - the information about him going to china (the active one).

So basically, if during one assignment (between `effective_start_date` and `effective_end_date`) there is information about him going to 2 different countries, I need to only show one case. I need to correct my select statement so it handles this case somehow.

**Edit :** This also needs to work when the 2 cases about employee going to another country are historical so I dont think this can be done with sysdate.

Edit nr.2 - updated sql fiddle. I need to show BOTH expatriations for person 321 and ony one for person 123 - this is basically my main goal.

Edit nr.3 - still havent found the solution.
[LINK TO SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/2915/0)

[image]

```
select 
    ass.person_id, 
    ass.effective_start_date,
    ass.effective_end_date,
    exp.date_from, 
    exp.date_to, 
    exp.home_country, 
    exp.host_country
from expatriates exp, assignments ass
where 
    exp.person_id=ass.person_id
and exp.date_to >= ass.effective_start_date
and exp.date_to <= ass.effective_end_date
```

Comment: Try to provide your data in a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e7720/3) that help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @PuneetPandey already wrote your logic will not catch all overlapping periods.

To get only one row you can use ROW_NUMBER, e.g.

```
select *
from
 (
   select 
       ass.person_id, 
       ass.effective_start_date,
       ass.effective_end_date,
       exp.date_from, 
       exp.date_to, 
       exp.home_country, 
       exp.host_country,
       row_number() 
       over (partition by ass.person_id, ass.effective_start_date
             order by exp.date_from) as rn
   from expatriates exp, assignments ass
   where 
       exp.person_id=ass.person_id 
   and exp.date_to >= ass.effective_start_date
   and exp.date_to <= ass.effective_end_date
 ) dt
where rn = 1
```

Comment: This won't work in case one employee is travelling to two different countries and correct date ranges are entered in assignments table. In that case i would need to retrieve both records.

Comment: @user3014914: In this case you probably have to change the calculation to  `(partition by ass.person_id, ass.effective_start_date`

Comment: This helped me a lot, it gave me an idea to come up with an even better solution, thanks!

Comment: @user3014914: Can you add your solution to the question?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think the query needs to be changed -

`and exp.date_to <= ass.effective_end_date` to `and exp.date_from <= ass.effective_end_date`.

Now, if you want any of the visited country, you can select distinct record by personid as below -

```
select 
distinct ass.person_id, 
ass.effective_start_date,
ass.effective_end_date,
exp.date_from, 
exp.date_to, 
exp.home_country, 
exp.host_country
from expatriates exp, assignments ass
where 
exp.person_id=ass.person_id
and exp.date_to >= ass.effective_start_date
and exp.date_from <= ass.effective_end_date
```

or, if you want a particular row, you can probably maintain another column for status and have that as '1' if the visit is active else keep that as '0' and use below query -

```
select 
ass.person_id, 
ass.effective_start_date,
ass.effective_end_date,
exp.date_from, 
exp.date_to, 
exp.home_country, 
exp.host_country
from expatriates exp, assignments ass
where 
exp.person_id=ass.person_id
and exp.date_to >= ass.effective_start_date
and exp.date_from <= ass.effective_end_date
and exp.status = 1
```

Comment: Your 1st solution - i can't change this logic. If date_to is between effective_start_date and effective_end_date then i need to gather the data, that's the logic i absolutely need to use. In assignments table there need to be entered dates when employee is visiting another country. I just need to handle cases when there isn't.

2nd solution - unfortunately there is no way i can obtain another column,

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to join a third table which will a derived table like "X" below:

```
select 
    ass.person_id, 
    ass.effective_start_date,
    ass.effective_end_date,
    exp.date_from, 
    exp.date_to, 
    exp.home_country, 
    exp.host_country
from expatriates exp, assignments ass, (
    SELECT e.person_id, MAX(e.date_from) md
    FROM expatriates e
    INNER JOIN assignments a ON e.person_id=a.person_id
    and e.date_to >= a.effective_start_date
    and e.date_to <= a.effective_end_date GROUP BY e.person_id) X
where exp.person_id= X.person_id
and exp.date_from= X.md
```

Comment: Yes but then what if both records are historical and in assignments there is entered correct date range? then some records will disappear.

Comment: Please see my updated sqlfiddle. My goal is to show one row for person 123 and both rows for 321.

Comment: Understood. Then I think you will need to change the inside of the derived table "X". Assignments table needed to be joined to the expatriates table inside of "X"..

Comment: I dont' think i understand the logic you are stating. Could you please provide me with a code sample?

Comment: I updated the code according to my advice! I hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming if a person get fired `effective_end_date` will be updated and no more `expatriates` record will appear. So I just select the last `date_to` in `expatriates`. That is why I dont see why you need compare date ranges and remove that part from my where.

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/2914)

```
active_or_last_ass AS (
    SELECT exp.person_id, date_from, max(exp.date_to) max_date
    FROM expatriates exp
    WHERE exp.date_from < sysdate
    GROUP BY exp.person_id, date_from
)   
select 
    ass.person_id, 
    ass.effective_start_date,
    ass.effective_end_date,
    exp.date_from, 
    exp.date_to, 
    exp.home_country, 
    exp.host_country
from 
    active_or_last_ass ala
    inner join expatriates exp 
       on  exp.person_id = ala.person_id
       and exp.date_to = ala.max_date
    inner join assignments ass
       on exp.person_id = ass.person_id
```

Comment: but what if there are correct date ranges entered in assignments table? then only one record will be gathered. Person CAN have multiple expatriations, as long as there are correct date ranges entered in assignments table that will match them. Your subquery suggests that a person can have ony one.

Comment: I update with sysdate... so now show the last active... even when a future expatriate is schedule. If you have a case didnt work please provide a fiddle with sample data and expected result.

Comment: i will try. i will add a case when a person has multiple expatriations and they have correct assignment dates entered.

Comment: sqlfiddle updated. She query should show only 1 expatriation for person 123 and both expatriations for person 321

Comment: How come in your [SAMPLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aad73/14) 123 `EXP.data_from` date is before `ASS.efective_start` ??